# Grails paginate issue, buttons are not rendering and the links do not seem to work either

Tags: grails, button, pagination

I have a basic grails entry page showing a list of events for a ticket system.

I am experiencing a paginate buttons problem in that the page 1 2 links are not looking like buttons and the word next is also just a hyperlink and it is not spaced out from the 2.

Secondly, the links themselves, once click on them do not work. They throw an error page:

```
--------------------------------
HTTP Status 404 - /tictoc/store/activeEvents
type Status report
message /tictoc/store/activeEvents
description The requested resource (/tictoc/store/activeEvents) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.25
--------------------------------


![page UI][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABPlB.png
```

Here is the Show.gsp... the paginate section is where I think my issue is:

```
<%@ page import="tictoc.Store" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'store.label', default: 'Store')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1> Ticket Store </h1>

        <table border=0 class="eventsTable">
            <tr>

                <th>Event</th>
                <th>Start </th>
                <th>End </th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <g:each var="event" in="${events}">

            <tr>

                <td>${event.name}</td>
                <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.startDate}"/></td>
                <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.endDate}"/></td>
                <td>${event.desc}</td>
            </tr>

            </g:each>
        </table>

        <div class="paginateButtons">
            <g:paginate controller="store"
                action="activeEvents"
                params="[name:active]"
                total="${totalEvents}" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller... 
I am not sure if the issue is here or not but I thought
I would include it just in case.

---

```
package tictoc

import tictoc.Event 

class StoreController {

    Event event
    static defaultAction = "activeEvents"

    def show = {
        log.error 'exec activeEvents'
        activeEvents()
    }

    def activeEvents = {
        log.error 'exec activeEvents'

        def max    = Math.min(params.max?.toInteger() ?:10, 100)
        def offset = params.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0
        def total =  Event.count()
        def eventList = Event.getAll()

        return [events:eventList, 
                       totalEvents:total,
                       active:params.active]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a few things going on:

1. The display of your pagination controls is likely a CSS issue.  I imagine you have customized or replaced the default Grails `web-app/css/main.css` file?  If so, try adding and tailoring the rules (below) to your application's CSS file.
2. If I follow your example, your .gsp file is `store/show.gsp`?    Since you are not specifying a view name in the `activeEvents` return statement, Grails by default looks for `store/activeEvents.gsp` and will return an error if this files does not exist.  You have a few options here, depending how you want to structure your application.  (a) You could change your `<g:paginate>` tags to reference the `show` action, (b) you could create the `store/activeEvents.gsp` view, or (c) you could modify your activeEvents return statement to explicitly use your existing `show` view: `render(view: "show", model: [events: eventList, ...])`
3. To allow pagination control values to carry over as you page through results, one option is to do something like this:

   ```
   def list = {
       params.max = Math.min(params.int('max', 25), 100);
       params.offset = params.int('offset', 0)
       params.sort = params.sort ?: "name";
       params.order = params.order ?: "asc";
       return [ myList: DomainObject.list(params) ]
   }
   ```

Default Grails 2.0 pagination CSS:

```
.paginateButtons {
    background: #fff url(../images/skin/shadow.jpg) bottom repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 0;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 3px;
}
.paginateButtons a {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #ccc #aaa #aaa #ccc;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
}
.paginateButtons span {
    padding: 2px 3px;
}
```

Comment: The buttons look right now. That was good. I changed the page / paginate to use the show closure... and now the next page works... except it shows the same items. And I can't seem to change number of items per page being shown. I tried to def max    = Math.min(params.max?.toInteger() ?:5, 5)

Comment: Right, another change is needed.  In your controller, replace `Event.getAll()` with `Event.list(params)`

Comment: Also, I edited my answer to include a sample Controller `list` closure.  You'll need to adapt it for your specific case.

Comment: Should using: def max    = Math.min(params.int('max', 5), 100); make the pagination show 5 max per page? If so I am seeing 10 still. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See bullet #3 in the revised answer.  Rather than `def max = `, you'll want to use `params.max = `  so that your max value is used by the `list(params)` call.